# Python: list index out of range error; certain list elements work

Tags: python, list, indexing

I'm using the divmod() function and am attempting to run my integer variable and list of integers sequentially through it. I used a for loop to try and receive two pairs of value for every element in my list 'test', but I can't seem to get any element in my list (except element [1] and [2] ) to be printed with divmod().

The code is supposed to run like:

1. User inputs a
2. User inputs b
3. b is divided by every element in list 'test', and the quotient and remainder is found.
4. This would print 4 pairs of values, 8 values in total.

This is what is happening:

1. User inputs a
2. User inputs b
3. b is divided by the [1] and [2] positions in the list (this case would be 2 and 5).
4. This prints 2 pairs of values, 4 values in total.
5. IndexError: list index out of range" is returned after because of my line:
   print divmod(b, test[i])

Here is the code:

```
test = [1, 2, 5, 10]
a = int(raw_input('Input: '))
b = int(raw_input('Input: '))
for i in test:
    print divmod(b, test[i])
```

I can do it like this:

```
print divmod(b, 1)
print divmod(b, 2)
print divmod(b, 5)
print divmod(b, 10)
```

or:

```
print divmod(b, test[0])
print divmod(b, test[1])
print divmod(b, test[2])
print divmod(b, test[3])
```

However, it seems inefficient and redundant, and I feel there is a better way to put the elements in a list to a function without having to individually call each one?

Comment: `divmod(b, i)`, `i` is the element not an index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The valid indexes of `test` are:

```
test[0]   #which is 1
test[1]   #which is 2
test[2]   #which is 5
test[3]   #which is 10
```

Any index past `3` is out of range.

If you just want to pass the values in one by one from `test`, just do

```
for i in test:
    print divmod(b, i)
```

This is different from what you wrote:

```
for i in test:
    print divmod(b, test[i])
```

This would try to execute:

```
print divmod(b, test[1])        # ok, though not the element you want
print divmod(b, test[2])        # ok, though not the element you want
print divmod(b, test[5])        # out of range!
print divmod(b, test[10])       # out of range!
```

Comment: Yes, thank you. I wonder what divmod(b, test[i]) did? It was going past 3?

Comment: Yes it does indeed go past `3`. See my edit to see what that would produce. In Python, `for i in test` will loop over each *value* in the list `test`, not each *index*.

Answer (score 0):

you probably like to do:

```
for i in test:
    print divmod(b, i)
```